# Is there an implementation of ZMQ in Octave

Tags: octave, zeromq

After googling a bit, I did not find anything that stroke as really useful.

I was wondering if there was any ZMQ interface implemented for Octave, I know there is something in Matlab, but I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a port of the matlab version which works great in octave (under ubuntu).  So far it's working great for what I need:

https://github.com/esromneb/zeromq-octave

The library has a few limitations (for instance publish always connects out and subscribe always binds to a port) but if you can live with that it's great!

Comment: +1 a cool move, man. Do you support or plan to support also other than PUB/SUB scenarios? On a brief look into ported-MEX source, { tcp | ipc | pgm }-transport classes are visible, but not other behaviour models than PUB/SUB. Was that my fault not to find others or an author's intention?

Comment: In order to support what you want I would need to re-write the entire library to support all of zmq.  This is something I might need to do in the future for my job, but as of today and this week the library is complete for my needs

Answer (score -1):

There is a zeromq package available from octave forge which works in octave under linux and windows.

You should be able to install it in octave by running:

pkg install -forge zeromq

(assuming you also have the zeromq library installed)

It supports most of the socket types, including pub/sub, req/rep, push/pull.

Details of the package can be found here: http://octave.sourceforge.net/zeromq/

Comment: -1 for answer that is the package in octave-forge, Should work in all OSs. And is the only one of the 2 mentioned here that still has development on it.